# What file generated output

Tags: debugging

I was debugging by adding a `print_r()` to my code to check array values along the way. The problem is I forgot where (which module and which file) I had added the `print_r()` statement since it has been some time I had worked on it. Now some of my pages are outputting an unwanted array print out. Is there a way to find out which module and which file specifically generated the array print out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running on Gnu/Linux or Unix, you should be able to position yourself above the directory holding your code and use the following shell command:

```
grep -r print_r .
```

This will recursively search through the current directory and all the directories below it for the string "print_r" and print out all lines containing that string, prefixed with its file name.

For future debugging, I suggest you install the [Devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel) module for debugging.  At least one of its debug printout functions (`dpm()`) will print where the debug statement is placed by name of file and line number if the object is complex enough to produce a Krumo accordion display of the object/array.

For simpler objects, use the second argument to `dpm()` to remind yourself where you placed it. E.g.:

```
dpm($uid, 'mymodule, line 42, $uid');
```